# What does "6473 6474 6475-xxx" mean in "Lenovo ThinkPad T400 6473 6474 6475-xxx"?

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop

What does `6473 6474 6475-xxx` mean in `Lenovo ThinkPad T400 6473 6474 6475-xxx`, in the name of a RAM product here ([http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A8NX3CQ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A8NX3CQ))?

How can I know if my T400 belongs to this series `6473 6474 6475-xxx`? My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.
The bottom of my laptop  says

> Product ID: 2764CTO
>
> Type-Model: 2764-CTO

So does it not belong to `T400 6473 6474 6475-xxx`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "type" on a Lenovo Thinkpad is a 4 digit number that is a unique identifier for the hardware specifications in the laptop.  For example, a laptop that has 8GB of RAM and one that only has 4GB could have a different 4 digit identifier.  The "CTO" is an acronym for "custom to order" which basically means you picked what parts you want in the computer rather than getting a base model or one of the official Lenovo packages.

The T400 will take up to 8GB of DDR3 RAM I believe.